# Graphing Rational Functions: Identifying the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics, graphing-functions, rational-functions

[image][Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U44JT.png)   [image: Graph Components]

I could find the Horizontal & Vertical Asymptotes, Domain, and root, but I still had difficulty finding the equation. I tried utilizing Desmos but fell short. Any ideas of what it might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods we can utilize to narrow down the possible equations for this function. [This](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:poly-graphs) is an excellent resource for understanding more on how you can find the equation of a polynomial from its graph, but I will try to briefly explain each of those methods.

Any root, or $x$-intercept, of the graph will be a zero of the polynomial. That is, $(x-a)$ will be a factor of a polynomial which has $p(a)=0$ and an $x$-intercept at $x=a$. The multiplicity of this root, or the number of factors of $(x-a)$ that exist for the polynomial, depends on the graph's behavior around $x=a$. If the graph crosses the $x$-axis, the multiplicity is an odd number. You can understand this intuitively because an odd multiplicity means that a change in the sign of $(x-a)$ changes the sign of the product of all the $(x-a)$ terms. Similarly, if the graph is only tangent to the $x$-axis at $x=a$, then the root $a$ has an even multiplicity. Since this is the case with this particular graph, we can know that the function contains an even number of $(x-1)$ terms.

Using similar logic, there must exist more $(x+3)$ and $(x-5)$ terms in the denominator of the function than in the numerator. This is because the graph has vertical asymptotes at $x=-3$ and $x=5$, and that means that the function approaches $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $-3$ and $5$. However, the $(x+3)$ term is actually a $-(x+5)$ or a $(-x-3)$ term. Think of it in this way. If $x<-3$, $\pm (x+3)>0$, assuming the rest of the function is positive. If $x > -3$, $\pm (x+3)<0$. This means that the term is actually $(-x-3)$ and not $(x+3)$.

Now let's look at the horizontal asymptote. If the numerator and denominator are the same degree polynomials, the numerator divided by the denominator approaches a certain number as $x$ approaches $\infty$ or $-\infty$. This number is the horizontal asymptote. This means that the highest degree term in the numerator is the highest degree term in the denominator times $5$.

Finally, let's talk about the horizontal discontinuity. A discontinuity only happens at a point $c$ if the term $(x-c)$ is there in the numerator and the denominator the same number of times, meaning that they cancel out, leaving only an undefined value at $x=c$. Since this point is at $x=3$, the term $(x-3)$ occurs in the numerator and denominator the same number of times.

Now let's construct a function. Using the above constraints, the function $f(x) = \dfrac{5(x-1)(x-1)(x-3)}{(x+3)(x-5)(x-3)}$ seems like it could work. [Graphing this in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/figich1vlz) gives us a graph that pretty much looks the exact same as your initial graph!

[image]

However, it's very important to note that this is only ***one*** of many possible functions holding these properties. $g(x) = \dfrac{5(x-1)(x-1)(x-3)\mathbf{(x+3)}}{(x+3)(x-5)(x-3)\mathbf{(x+3)}}$ works just as well, for example. The properties mentioned above hold for all possible functions (the number of $(x-a)$ terms, for example), but the function can be anything where these properties hold true.

PS: Your answer seems to be right, except for the fact that it's $(x-1)^2$ in the numerator, and not $(x+1)^2$ :) Again, I stress on the fact that this is only ***one*** of the possible functions, and not the ***only*** possible function.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to not only help come to a conclusion but with a beautiful explanation well. I realized the issue was that I accidentally placed an absolute value between the (x+3) and (x-5) within the denominator. So yes that answer is correct. Once again thank you.

Comment: You're welcome; it's my pleasure :)